# Multiple XSD schemas for castor with castor-maven-plugin

Tags: maven, castor

Is it possible to work with multiple xsd schemas with castor-maven-plugin simultaneously?

I use it in rotation (schema1 and schema2) in POM and it works:

```
<build>
    ...
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>castor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <schema>src/main/castor/schema1.xsd</schema>
                <dest>src/main/java</dest>
                <packaging>com.path.to.schema1.beans</packaging>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

...

with a little problem: mvn:install collects all classes to target  except **chema2.crd** (or schema1 if I use schema2). I have to copy file manually.

Can I fix it? Are there any ways to configure castor-maven-plugin ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using multiple executions like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>castor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>firstSchema</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <schema>src/main/castor/schema1.xsd</schema>
              <dest>src/main/java</dest>
              <packaging>com.path.to.schema1.beans</packaging>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>secondSchema</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <schema>src/main/castor/schema2.xsd</schema>
              <dest>src/main/java</dest>
              <packaging>com.path.to.schema2.beans</packaging>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Much thanks! It works. But you should add <id> tags into each <execution> to identifire each of it.

Comment: Good catch!  I cut-n-pasted what was in the question to create the answer and missed that the ID wasn't there.  It's fixed now.

Comment: Somehow it just worked using `generate-sources` goal. Trying with `castor:generate` just didn't take the execution configuration